How do I make the following puzzle on-topic?
How do I make the following puzzle on-topic?
a. Just ask people to solve it.
b. Post the puzzle with the answer and ask which hint is not accurate


Recklessly run around

Make things up

A big mistake is made

Better be independent

King among Kings

buried talent

Become a bandit

To do a good job, you must prepare your tools

give as charity

die for a cause


A. Crisscrossing
B. Do whatever you want
C. Winner writes the history
D. Trespassing
E. nonsense
F. Looking for trouble
G. Before the army can move
H. Never say no
I. busy traffic
J. late bloomer
K. Want for nothing
L. Don't do things to people you don't want to be done to you
If the blank one is too hard, you can try this one with additional hints


In my opinion, there isn't a sensible way to make this on-topic by means of wording, title, etc. as it currently stands. It's just a game.
It's also an undue burden on the author to force something with such a very specific raison d'être into some arbitrary format — StackExchange general on-topic rules are arbitrary, relative to other forums and social networks.
The only way is that the community declares puzzles like this on-topic, so that authors and solvers can simply participate without being concerned with how to make it fit the format.

I feel like it's more manageable in text form.  Assuming I haven't messed it up, that is:

．．．．．．．．．．．．．  Across    
．．．．①．．②．．．．．  ③ Crisscrossing
．③④＃＃．．＃．⑤．．．  ⑥ Do whatever you want
．．＃．＃．．⑥＃＃＃．．  ⑦ Winner writes the history
．．＃．⑦⑧＃＃．＃．．．  ⑨ Trespassing
．⑨＃．．＃．．．＃．．．  ⑩ nonsense
．．．⑩＃＃＃．⑪＃＃＃．  ⑪ Looking for trouble
．．．＃．＃．．．＃．．．  ⑫ Before the army can move
．．．＃．．．⑫＃＃＃．．  ⑬ Never say no
．．．⑬⑭＃＃．．＃．⑮．  ⑯ busy traffic
．．．．＃．．．．＃．＃．  ⑰ late bloomer
．．⑯＃＃＃．．⑰＃＃＃．  ⑲ Want for nothing
．．．．＃．⑱．．．．＃．  ⑳ Don't do things to people you don't want to be done to you
．⑲＃＃＃．＃．．．．．．  
．．．．⑳＃＃＃＃㉑＃＃．  Down
．．．．．．＃．．＃．．．  ① A big mistake is made
．．．．．．．．．．．．．  ② Become a bandit
　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ④ Recklessly run around
　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑤ To do a good job, you must prepare your tools
　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑧ King among Kings
　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑩ Make things up
　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑭ Better be independent
　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑮ die for a cause
　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ⑱ buried talent
　　　　　　　　　　　　　  ㉑ give as charity


And here are the hints in both traditional and simplified.

．．．．．．．．．．．．．     ．．．．．．．．．．．．．  
．．．．大．．＃．．．．．     ．．．．大．．＃．．．．．  
．＃＃交＃．．＃．＃．．．     ．＃＃交＃．．＃．＃．．．  
．．＃．＃．．为＃＃＃．．     ．．＃．＃．．為＃＃＃．．  
．．＃．＃＃败＃．＃．．．     ．．＃．＃＃敗＃．＃．．．  
．＃撞．．＃．．．＃．．．     ．＃撞．．＃．．．＃．．．  
．．．＃＃＃谈．＃＃生＃．     ．．．＃＃＃談．＃＃生＃．  
．．．中．王．．．必．．．     ．．．中．王．．．必．．．  
．．．＃．．．＃草＃＃．．     ．．．＃．．．＃草＃＃．．  
．．．＃＃＃应．．＃．＃．     ．．．＃＃＃應．．＃．＃．  
．．．．人．．．．＃．＃．     ．．．．人．．．．＃．＃．  
．．＃流＃＃．．＃器＃＃．     ．．＃流＃＃．．＃器＃＃．  
．．．．＃．＃．．．．仁．     ．．．．＃．＃．．．．仁．  
．＃＃无＃．才．．．．．．     ．＃＃無＃．才．．．．．．  
．．．．＃＃＃欲＃＃＃＃．     ．．．．＃＃＃欲＃＃＃＃．  
．．．．．．＃．．＃．．．     ．．．．．．＃．．＃．．．  
．．．．．．．．．．．．．     ．．．．．．．．．．．．．  


Ordinarily at Puzzling.SE, hints are not given until after giving people some time (maybe a week).  If someone can figure it out without a hint, then hints are not necessary.
Beyond this, it'll need a title that's more meaningful than just "idiom crossword", which should indicate the commonality between the answers.
I also recommend adding some idea of the level of this puzzle: how hard is it?  It looks hard to me.

To a native speaker, it should be around 2 -3 on a scale of 1- 5. For non-native, I am afraid it is 4-5

I'll come back after a few more years of study then (:.  (I was hoping "nonsense" = 胡说八道 and "buried talent" would be "crouching tiger hidden dragon", but neither are correct.  Oh well...)

That's without additional hints. With the hints, the degree of difficulty would drop down one number,

At my level, we know maybe 5 chengyu: 人山人海, 不可思议, umm... 与众不同 and 独一无二.  Oh 愚公移山.  And maybe 马马虎虎, if that counts.

Should I post the answer?

I'd give people the challenge of solving it first.  Otherwise, what's the point?

Formatting per-se doesn't make it on-topic. The other questions were closed as opinion-based. Consensus does make it on-topic

I think we're looking at this from two different starting points:  I think of it as inherently on-topic (along the lines of an effortful translation question), and would expect a consensus before declaring it off-topic.

@Becky 李蓓 You mean I should just post it without the answer and let it sit for months? Just ask "please solve it" , It has a definite answer, so it wouldn't be opinion-based
